# Object not Moving?

Tags: java, object, keyboard, move, velocity

I am making a Java game, but I have a problem. My object is not moving:

Here is some code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject temp = handler.object.get(i);
        if (temp.getC() == Char.StarPlayer && Stardust.keyEnabled){
            System.out.println("test");
            System.out.println(temp.getY());
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) temp.setY(-5);
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) temp.setVelY(5);
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) temp.setVelX(-5);
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) temp.setVelX(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I am getting any "GameObject" that has the Character ID "StarPlayer" (Char.StarPlayer) attached to it, and also when the keyboard is enabled (keyEnabled). It seems to work well when it gets here, as it does output "test" and the object's Y value into the console. However, the object does not actually MOVE. Everytime I press it, the object should be at a different Y level, but the console keeps saying the same number everytime I press it. I don't know what is happening! I am setting the velocity, and as you can see in this code of the "StarPlayer":

```
public void tick(){
    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    y = Stardust.clamp(y, 0, Stardust.HEIGHT - 64);
    x = Stardust.clamp(x, 0, Stardust.WIDTH - 32);



}
```

The velocity is added to the actual x value to make it move. It has worked before, but for some reason it isn't working now.

Please help as soon as possible ;)
- Blockhead7360

EDIT: Clamp does not interrupt this (I don't think). This same thing has worked before, and for some reason does not work now....

I guess here is clamp if you need it:

```
public static int clamp(int var, int min, int max){
    if (var >= max){
        return var = max;
    }else if (var <= min){
        return var = min;
    }else return var;
}
```

EDIT 2: I tried taking out CLAMP and it still did not move?!?

EDIT 3: I GOT IT TO WORK! Basically, instead of spawning the player where I did from one of my classes, I spawned it in another one! It seemed to work ;)

Comment: can you tell us where is tick() called ? and what does clamp() do?

Comment: @svasa tick is called every 1/60 of a second. Clamp stops it from going outside of the screen

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you update x and y, but then immediately after that you set them to something else with `clamp()`.

```
public void tick(){
    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    y = Stardust.clamp(y, 0, Stardust.HEIGHT - 64); // This (might) be your problem
    x = Stardust.clamp(x, 0, Stardust.WIDTH - 32);
}
```

Without knowing what `clamp()` does I can't say that that is for sure the issue, but it seems likely.

Comment: I don't think clamp is bothering it. This worked before, and for some reason isn't working now in this class. @Kironide